# String replace with another character C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

my messages normally comes like this in SMSgateway(gateway forwarded the message to our application),

> sett pØll 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 121011 ( this message is correct )

But some cases this message comes like,

> sett p&oslas;ll 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 121011 (this message incorrect,Ø comes with &oslas;)

this message comes as a string,when message comes &oslas; i need to replace it to Ø.
sometimes it comes with another name, like gordØn(gord&oslas;n) It always stat with & sign & endsup with ; sign.

Here i tries to do it,but my knowledge is not enough to complete this..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        string mobileNo = Request.QueryString["msisdn"];
        int  dest = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["shortcode"].ToString());
        string messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];
        string operatorNew = Request.QueryString["operator"];

        string []reparr = messageIn.Split(' ');//split it & then check contains
        reparr[1].Contains = '&';
        reparr[1].Contains = ';';
        // In here i need to check that character & replace it to originalone.


        Label1.Text = "ok";

        WriteToFile(mobileNo, dest, messageIn, operatorNew,true,"","");
```

Comment: I mean, you can conceivably do `messageIn.Replace("&oslas;", "ø");`, but I think that using `HtmlDecode` is more flexible.

Comment: when i add HtmlDecode then after the &, all the character missing.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like HTML entities. You can try to decode them using [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx):

```
string messageIn = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["msg"]);
```

Comment: i think you can't use this function,OP needs String replace

Comment: he ask about when some character inside the &xxxx; then how to replace with original Ø; character

Comment: Yes, but `&xxxx;` are commonly known as HTML entities. Since he gets the data from a web form, it makes sense that the input might contain HTML entities. Using a library function is much easier than trying to deal with the hundreds of defined HTML entities.

Comment: @nneonneo ya then how to replace it with original characters ?

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad: That's what `HtmlDecode` does: it takes stuff like `%amp;` and `&oslash;` and replaces it with the proper characters `&` and `ø`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode to decode the url
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx

Comment: That seems to be the wrong function; it decodes URLs (`%20`), not HTML entities (`&amp;`).

Comment: querystring is supposed to be from url.

Comment: he ask about when some character inside the &xxxx; then how to replace with original Ø character

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe Ranasinghe ya.exactly that i need.In here there's no any problem with query string

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about web namespace utilities but you may use below code (if position of & and ; is always going to be in beginning of message and these characters will not appear inside message text):

```
String s = @"sett p&oslas;ll 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 121011";
Int32 startIndex = s.IndexOf("&");
String s1 = s.Replace(s.Substring(startIndex, s.IndexOf(";") - startIndex + 1), "Ø");
```

Comment: So, what happens if there are two Ø in the text?

Comment: OP didn't explain anything related to this. OP is expecting Ø character to be missing when invalid value is coming and if Ø is coming then value is valid. Of course the code will need to handle all the scenarios.